# How to solve this type of ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$f''（t)+\cos(t) f(t)=0$$
where double prime means the second derivative.
Is there a name for this type of ODE?

Comment: Is there a name?  Second-order linear homogeneous differential equation.  For that particular one, Maple shows a solution in terms of Mathieu functions $C$ and $S$.  Knowing that, I find that your DE is an instance of Mathieu's differential equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function

Comment: @GEdgar Sorry, I mean whether this equation has been named by some mathematician or does it have a special name. I think it looks so simple such that it has been studied in detail. But I do not know how to solve it. And that is my question in this post.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks a lot! Thats pecisely what I need!

Comment: You might check out Hill's equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_differential_equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is given by $$y(t)=c_1 \text{MathieuC}\left[0,-2,\frac{t}{2}\right]+c_2
   \text{MathieuS}\left[0,-2,\frac{t}{2}\right]$$